# Capture VS Code terminal output

Tags: typescript, api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VS Code extension. I need to capture the output of the integrated terminal and store it in a variable when I run a command through the command palette.

I am aware that it's a Proposed APIs(https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Extension-API-process). What could be the best possible solution?