# How to capture debug output by a VS Code Extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm curious about how to capture the debug output content by a vs code extension. The situation is, that I'm developing a vs code extension that aims to monitor the debugging process of projects in any programming language, and the core question is, how can I get the debug output content of the software project which is open by the vs code?

I checked the APIs of both DebugConsole and DebugSession and have no clue yet. And Copilot told me "The Debug Console's output is not exposed to the API, likely due to the potential for security risks or performance issues." but I'm not quite sure if it's hallucination again.

Anyone can share your experience on this? That would be very appreciated!

- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DebugConsole
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DebugSession
- [Capture VS Code terminal output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320413/capture-vs-code-terminal-output)